# How to access the response of a get request from ClientBuilder

Tags: java, api, get

I'm using a ClientBuilder to asynchronously perform multiple GET requests from an API.

```
private static Future<Response> getElevation(Coordinate coordinate) {
    double latatude = coordinate.getLatatude();
    double longatude = coordinate.getLongatude();
    String url = "https://api.open-elevation.com/api/v1/lookup?locations=" + latatude + "%2C%20" + longatude;
    System.out.println("URL : " + url);
    return ClientBuilder.newClient().target(url).request().async().get();
}
```

I call the above method and then wait until the request has been complete by using the command ...

```
.isDone()
```

on the object of type Future<,Response>. However I don't know how to get the actual response from this. I know it should have the form as such;

```
{"results": [{"latitude": 53.95798659954082, "elevation": 0, "longitude": -4.306156617942942}]}
```

I've tride, .getResult.toString() and just .toString(). But cannot see what else there is.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call `get()` on the returned `Future<Response>` object:

```
get()
Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.
```

See the documentation of the [`Future<V>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html?is-external=true) Interface.

Comment: Thanks. Although using get() returns an object of type Response in my case, not a string that I can use.